# Repeated svg background gaps in safari

Tags: css, svg, safari, background-image

I created the following codepen to demonstrate the problem:

http://codepen.io/perrin4869/pen/rWdWMm

In Chrome, Firefox and IE11 it works as expected - the background gets repeated horizontally. However, in Safari, at specific heights of the document, such as 439px, you can see gaps between the repetitions of the svg background image...
I have tried changing settings of the svg, such as making the `width`, `height`, `viewport` values be all whole integers, and tried the `preserveAspectRatio` property with all the possible values, but the gaps remain...

Anyone got a clue why this is happening, and how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I can only guess  (no safari at hand :-(  )... but try, in your svg, shape-rendering="crispEdges". That might help... this helps if gaps appear between shapes in one svg file. I don'the know if it helps externaly though...

Comment: @HolgerWill, thanks for the response! I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work =/

Comment: well, was worth a try. thanks for the feedback, good to know...

Comment: You are specifying `preserveAspectRatio="none"` in your SVG. Which may well help your problem, but the trouble is that you are also specifying a `width` and `height` that is exactly the same as your `viewBox`. So the `preserveAspectRatio` is not effective. Try changing both `width` and `height` to `"100%"`.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau thanks for the suggestion! Actually, without `preserveAspectRatio="none"` I do get some glitches.I just tried your suggestion too, set `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` with `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"`, but the gaps are still there. Tried to play around with `preserveAspectRatio` a bit but no luck...

Comment: I was suggesting you try `width="100%" height="100%"  preserveAspectRatio="none"`

Comment: @PaulLeBeau yeah that's the first thing I tried, but it distorted the svg from a bunch of arcs to a bunch of rectangles

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll help any. But have you tried using a specific size for the width in the background-size?  Eg. `background-size: 10vh 50vh;`

Comment: yup, gaps still there though...
at this point I suspect it's a  safari bug

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this. My solution was to set the background-size to 101%. It was the only thing I could think of that worked. Even though it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
   <!-- Your SVG content here -->
</svg>
```

Use shape-rendering Property: You can try using the shape-rendering property on your SVG elements to control the way they are rendered. Setting shape-rendering="crispEdges" can help avoid anti-aliasing and potentially reduce gaps.